# Android save gif from database to file

Tags: android, file, store, gif

In the database of my app i have stored a gif image as BLOB. How can i retrive this gif from database and save it to sdcard as gif file? For png and jpeg i know how to do it. How can i achieve this correctly without any library?
For png and jpeg i do like this code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream;
imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBlob);
Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
storeImage(image);


private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null) 
    {
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("MyApp", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("MyApp", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

//To Get the Path for Image Storage
private  File getOutputMediaFile(){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + contexto.getPackageName()
            + "/Files");


    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    File mediaFile;

    String mImageName="myImage.png";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);

    return mediaFile;
}
```

I tried below with no success. This doesnt create the file. I dont know what is wrong or if im missing something.

```
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBlob);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int len = 0;
while ((len = imageStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
stream.write(byteBuffer.toByteArray());
```

Need help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the format of the image in the DB?

Comment: The gif is stored as BLOB in the database. I want to retrieve it and save to file.

Comment: Yes, but how are the pixels encoded in that blob?

Comment: Show the code where you store the gif as blob. You first have to make code to retrieve the gif from the blob. You better change getOutputMediaFile() to use getExternalFilesDir(). Well you retrieve png and jpg but you both save them as png. Is that ok? Do you want to save the .gif as .jpg too?

Comment: I dont know the pixels. My app takes the blob from a server and stores it on database. I have no info about the pixels. I only know that the blob comes from a .gif file.

Comment: The code above its only an example. My objetive is to read the blob  from database and save it to .gif file on my sdcard. Only that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBlob);
```

Once you have that just save the stream to file. Don't make a bitmap of it and don't use BitmapFactory.  You can use that for png, jpg, and gif.